# Telegram Bot API. Не могу получить контакты пользователя. java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

В коде присутствую комментарии. Мне нужно получить номер телефона юзера. Апи телеграма позволяет это делать с помощью `keyboardButton.setText("Share your number >").setRequestContact(true);` то есть появляется запрос и юзер одним кликом отправляет свой контакт. После чего я пытаюсь отобразить его контакт в консоли `System.out.println(update.getMessage().getContact());`, но получаю  `null`

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
        long chat_id = update.getMessage().getChatId();

        if (update.getMessage().getText().equals("/start")) {

            SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage()
                    .setChatId(chat_id)
                    .setText("You send /start");

            // Создаем клавиуатуру
            ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
            sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(replyKeyboardMarkup);
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(true);
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setOneTimeKeyboard(true);

            // Создаем список строк клавиатуры
            List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();

            // Первая строчка клавиатуры
            KeyboardRow keyboardFirstRow = new KeyboardRow();
            // Добавляем кнопки в первую строчку клавиатуры
            KeyboardButton keyboardButton = new KeyboardButton();

            keyboardButton.setText("Share your number >").setRequestContact(true);
            keyboardFirstRow.add(keyboardButton);

            // Добавляем все строчки клавиатуры в список
            keyboard.add(keyboardFirstRow);
            // и устанваливаем этот список нашей клавиатуре
            replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);

            try {
                sendMessage(sendMessage);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("#############");
            System.out.println(update.getMessage().getContact());
            System.out.println("#############");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вопрос связан исключительно с особенностями реализации работы с апи для конкретной библиотеки, при этом нет ни кода, иллюстрирующего проблемные методы, ни ссылки на саму библиотеку

Comment: Про библиотеку не подумал. Вот библиотека https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots

Answer (score 1):

В общем через отладку заметил, что нужные данные в определенный момент все же добавляются. По этому методом проб и ошибок вынес код из if в котором идет запрос на телефон пользователя и все заработало.